# Do Objective-C objects get their own copies of instance methods?

Tags: objective-c

I'm new to Objective-C and was wondering if anyone could provide any information to clarify this for me. My (possibly wrong) understanding of object instantiation in other languages is that the object will get it's own copies of instance variables as well as instance methods, but I'm noticing that all the literature I've read thus far about Objective-C seems to indicate that the object only gets copies of instance variables, and that even when calling an instance method, program control reverts back to the original method defined inside the class itself. For example, this page from Apple's developer site shows program flow diagrams that suggest this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH4-SW1

Also in Kochan's "Programming in Objective-C", 6th ed., pg. 41, referring to an example fraction class and object, the author states that:

*"The first message sends the setNumerator: message to myFraction...control is then sent to the setNumerator: method you defined for your Fraction class...Objective-C...knows that it's the method from this class to use because it knows that myFraction is an object from the Fraction class"*

On pg. 42, he continues:

*"When you allocate a new object...enough space is reserved in memory to store the object's data, which includes space for its instance variables, plus a little more..."*

All of this would seem to indicate to me that there is only ever one copy of any method, the original method defined within the class, and when calling an instance method, Objective-C simply passes control to that original copy and temporarily "wires it" to the called object's instance variables. I know I may not be using the right terminology, but is this correct? It seems logical as creating multiple copies of the same methods would be a waste of memory, but this is causing me to rethink my entire understanding of object instantiation. Any input would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: You are correct. There is only ever one copy of the methods.

Comment: For virtually all O-O languages the instance methods are not copied when you create a class instance.  There's no need to, since the hidden zeroth parm of the method is a pointer to the instance, so the compiler can swizzle references to instance variables to be `hiddenPtr ->instanceVarx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct. The instance methods are shared by all instances of a class. The reason is, as you suspect, that doing it the other way would be a massive waste of memory.

The temporary wiring you speak of is that each method has an additional hidden parameter passed to it: a pointer to the calling object. Since that gives the method access to the calling object, then it can easily access all of the necessary instance variables and all is well. Note that any `static` variable exists in only a single instance as well and if you are not aware of that, unexpected things can happen. However, regular local variables are not shared and are recreated for each call of a method.

Apple's [documention](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtHowMessagingWorks.html) on the topic is very good so have a look for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Just think of a method as a set of instructions. There is no reason to have a copy of the same method for each object. I think you may be mistaken about other languages as well. Methods are associated with the class, not individual objects.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your thinking is more or less right (although it's simpler than that: behind the scenes in most such languages methods don't need to be "wired" to anything, they just take an extra parameter for `self` and insert struct lookups before references to instance variables).

What might be confusing you is that not all languages work this way, in their implementations and *semantically*. Object-oriented languages are (very roughly) divided into two camps: class-based, like Objective-C; and prototype-based, like Javascript. In the second camp of languages, a method or procedure really is an object in its own right and can often be assigned directly to an object's instance variables as well - there are no classes to lookup methods *from*, only objects and other objects, all with the same first-class status (this is an oversimplification, good languages still allow for sharing and efficiency).